# Salesforce doesn't like parenthesis in Lightning Component mark-up

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am building a reusable sidebar navigation component, however I am getting errors about parenthesis in my markup:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Map" default="
                                                     {
                                                        'Group 1': ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
                                                        'Group 2': ['Item 3']
                                                     }
                                                     " />

    <nav class="slds-nav-vertical" aria-label="Sub page">

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.items.keySet()}" var="item">
            <div class="slds-nav-vertical__section">
                <h2 id="entity-header" class="slds-nav-vertical__title slds-text-title_caps">{!item}</h2>
                <ul>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items.get(item)}" var="subItem">
                        <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header">{!subItem}</a></li>                        
                    </aura:iteration>
                </ul>
            </div>                        
        </aura:iteration>        
    </nav>
```

Salesforce doesn't like this line:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.items.keySet()}" var="item">
```

And this line:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.items.get(item)}" var="subItem">
```

If I cannot use parenthesis, how does one get items from a Map and its `keySet()`?

Comment: you cannot iterate a map in lightning components using aura:iteration you have to convert it to array of objects

Comment: So you are saying I need something like this: `<aura:attribute name="items" type="Object[]" default="{ ... }" />`? What about the use of parenthesis?

Comment: Yeah and the attribute data if you are getting it from server should also be sent in that format List<Object> format from apex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RedDevil pointed out, I needed to use an `Object[]` instead of a `Map`. Here's the working sidebar navigation component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Object[]" default="[ { headerLabel: 'Header 1', subItems: [ { label: 'Item 1', active: true, url: '#' }, { label: 'Item 2', url: '#' } ] }, { headerLabel: 'Header 2', subItems: [ { label: 'Item 3', url: '#' }, { label: 'Item 4', url: '#' } ] } ]" />
    <nav class="slds-nav-vertical" aria-label="Sub page">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
            <div class="slds-nav-vertical__section">
                <h2 id="entity-header" class="slds-nav-vertical__title slds-text-title_caps">{!item.headerLabel}</h2>
                <ul>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!item.subItems}" var="subItem">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!subItem.active}">
                            <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item slds-is-active"><a href="{!subItem.url}" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header">{!subItem.label}</a></li>                        
                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item"><a href="{!subItem.url}" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header">{!subItem.label}</a></li>                                
                            </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </ul>
            </div>                        
        </aura:iteration>        
    </nav>
</aura:component>
```