# Where to put initialization code for a reusable Salesforce Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have built a reusable [vertical navigation component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207037/salesforce-doesnt-like-parenthesis-in-lightning-component-mark-up). I plan on using this component across multiple pages and don't know where I am supposed to put the initialization code, which will set the menu headers and items. Obviously, if I do this in the component controller itself, it will be the same across all pages I use it on, so I need a way of setting page-specific initialization attribute values.

In traditional web app development, one could pass the initialization data through a page-level controller model, but how does one accomplish the same in a autonomous Lightning Component, such as the navigation component I referenced above?

I need to be able to set the `items` values differently, depending on the page the component is added to. It seems that I need to set the values externally from the component itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [design attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) for your component bundle

This way you can set different attributes for each component instance - and this is for app builder and for community builder

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I thought of that, but since the attribute is `Object[]`, this is not possible. Ergo, I am looking for a way to initialize the component on each page with different initialization `Object[]` values.

Comment: So put it as a string and stringify it when you put it in the community builder, then on your component code - in the init `JSON.parse` this string attribute

Comment: Thanks Itai, this is ultimately what I ended up doing. Appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign the value you want to use in the parent component to the items attribute of your component, and the framework will render your menu appropriately.

---

Any initialization you may need to do internally can be done using aura:valueInit:

```
<aura:handler name="init"
                      value="{!this}"
                      action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

And define it in your controller:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.items", ...)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the parent component is a Communities page? How do I assume attributes from there?

Comment: @SwisherSweet see edit. I'd this what you're looking for?

Comment: If I'm setting the `items` values inside the component itself, then this unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I need to be able to set the `items` values differently, depending on the page the component is added to. It seems that I need to set the values externally from the component itself.

Comment: @SwisherSweet You'd have to use a design attribute, as Itai mentioned. Since we only get native primitives basically, you might want to just do some post-processing in your init function.